# rexster.xml configuration with titan 0.5.4 and berkeleyje

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, rexster

Im new to graph db and I'm totally lost since few days. Im trying to run rexster with titan db 0.5.4 with berkeleyje storage backend. 
but I'm not sure if the rexster.xml configuration is correct.

if I follow the rexster [docs](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/wikidocs/rexster/2.5.0/Rexster-Configuration.html) I got in the doghouse empty db with no vertices or edges while actually there are. [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1sfozu3sf0ro82/Screenshot%202016-02-08%2000.28.36.png?dl=0)

```
  <graphs>
    <graph>
      <graph-name>bio4j</graph-name>
      <graph-type>com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.TinkerGraphGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
      <graph-location>/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Bio4j/bio4j/importGOTitanProperties.properties</graph-location>
      <graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
      <extensions>
        <allows>
          <allow>tp:frames</allow>
        </allows>
      </extensions>
    </graph>
    ...
  </graphs>
```

and if I follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397426/how-to-start-titan-graph-server-and-connect-with-gremlin?lq=1)

```
  <graphs>
    <graph>
      <graph-name>bio4j</graph-name>
      <graph-type>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graph-type>

      <graph-location>/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Bio4j/bio4j/importGOTitanProperties.properties</graph-location>
      <graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
      <properties>
        <storage.backend>local</storage.backend>
        <storage.directory>/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Bio4j/bio4j</storage.directory>
        <buffer-size>100</buffer-size>
      </properties>
      <extensions>
        <allows>
          <allow>tp:frames</allow>
        </allows>
      </extensions>
    </graph>
    ...
  </graphs>
```

I got these errors:

```
$ ../../bin/rexster.sh --start
0    [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application  - .:Welcome to Rexster:.
90   [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexsterProperties  - Using [/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Titan/rexhome/config/rexster.xml] as configuration source.
97   [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application  - Rexster is watching [/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Titan/rexhome/config/rexster.xml] for change.
232  [main] WARN  com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer  - Could not load graph bio4j. Please check the XML configuration.
233  [main] WARN  com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer  - GraphConfiguration could not be found or otherwise instantiated: [com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration]. Ensure that it is in Rexster's path.
com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationException: GraphConfiguration could not be found or otherwise instantiated: [com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration]. Ensure that it is in Rexster's path.
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFromConfiguration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:142)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.<init>(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:54)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.reconfigure(XmlRexsterApplication.java:99)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.<init>(XmlRexsterApplication.java:47)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.<init>(Application.java:97)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.main(Application.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: local
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:47)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:421)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:361)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1275)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:93)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:73)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration.configureGraphInstance(TitanGraphConfiguration.java:33)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFromConfiguration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:124)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: local
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:42)
    ... 12 more
235  [main] WARN  com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer  - Could not find implementation class: local
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: local
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:47)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:421)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:361)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1275)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:93)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:73)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration.configureGraphInstance(TitanGraphConfiguration.java:33)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFromConfiguration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:124)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.<init>(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:54)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.reconfigure(XmlRexsterApplication.java:99)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.<init>(XmlRexsterApplication.java:47)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.<init>(Application.java:97)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.main(Application.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: local
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:42)
    ... 12 more
244  [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.metrics.HttpReporterConfig  - Configured HTTP Metric Reporter.
245  [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.metrics.ConsoleReporterConfig  - Configured Console Metric Reporter.
1312 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.HttpRexsterServer  - HTTP/REST thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] worker[8 / 8] 
1313 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.HttpRexsterServer  - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollowerNIOStrategy IOStrategy for HTTP/REST.
1399 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.HttpRexsterServer  - Rexster Server running on: [http://localhost:8182]
1399 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollowerNIOStrategy IOStrategy for RexPro.
1399 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - RexPro thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] worker[8 / 8] 
1402 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - Rexster configured with [DefaultSecurity].
1403 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - RexPro Server bound to [0.0.0.0:8184]
1412 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.ShutdownManager  - Bound shutdown socket to /127.0.0.1:8183. Starting listener thread for shutdown requests.
```

and here is the db .properties file:

```
$ nano importGOTitanProperties.properties
#ImportGOTitan properties
storage.directory=bio4j
storage.backend=berkeleyje
#index.search.backend=elasticsearch
#index.search.directory=bio4j/es
storage.batch-loading=false
storage.transactions=true
query.fast-property=false
schema.default=none
```

Answer (score 1):

after reading [this](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/server.html) I could figure out how to configure the rexster.xml file

rexster.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rexster>
  ...
  <graphs>
    <graph>
      <graph-name>bio4j</graph-name>
      <graph-type>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
      <graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
      <properties>
        <storage.backend>berkeleyje</storage.backend>
        <storage.directory>/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Bio4j/bio4j</storage.directory>
        <storage.buffer-size>100</storage.buffer-size>
      </properties>
      <extensions>
        <allows>
          <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
        </allows>
      </extensions>
    </graph>
  </graphs>
</rexster>
```

starting the server:

```
$ ../../bin/rexster.sh --start
0    [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application  - .:Welcome to Rexster:.
115  [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexsterProperties  - Using [/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Titan/rexhome/config/rexster.xml] as configuration source.
129  [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application  - Rexster is watching [/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Titan/rexhome/config/rexster.xml] for change.
942  [main] INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Generated unique-instance-id=0a2581025086-AngryMac-local1
1049 [main] INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend  - Initiated backend operations thread pool of size 8
1161 [main] INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog  - Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time Timepoint[1454913673816000 μs] into com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@302c971f
1165 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.RexsterApplicationGraph  - Graph [bio4j] - configured with allowable namespace [tp:gremlin]
1205 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer  - Graph bio4j - titangraph[berkeleyje:/Users/Phoenix/Dropbox/Graph4Bio/Bio4j/bio4j] loaded
2502 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.HttpRexsterServer  - HTTP/REST thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] worker[8 / 8]
2504 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.HttpRexsterServer  - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollowerNIOStrategy IOStrategy for HTTP/REST.
2636 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.HttpRexsterServer  - Rexster Server running on: [http://localhost:8182]
2636 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollowerNIOStrategy IOStrategy for RexPro.
2636 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - RexPro thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] worker[8 / 8]
2640 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - Rexster configured with no security.
2641 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.RexProRexsterServer  - RexPro Server bound to [0.0.0.0:8184]
2653 [main] INFO  com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.ShutdownManager  - Bound shutdown socket to /127.0.0.1:8183. Starting listener thread for shutdown requests.
```

the doghouse [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/27fmmo6ttzecji2/Screenshot%202016-02-08%2014.41.47.png) :))))